# Why does the int in my model class return null

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am just wondering why my getTotal_Score() is null in my model class but I can retrieve it successfully from the database...I have tried both capital Integer and just a normal int, but that doesn't work...I have also tried Long type but I still get a null variable..The other thing that is puzzling me too is that when I use int type instead of long, it doesn't work.... Can you retrieve the numbers as int simple by doing:

```
int score = (int) snapshop.child("Glen Family Medical Centre").child("Total Score");
```

I can only get the above to work with long type...

```
public class Information {    // variables have to match in firebase database or it will show null
    private String Address;
    private String Name;
    private String Phone_No;
    private String Suburb;
    private String State;
    private String Postcode;
    private String Doctor;
    private int Total_Score;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Information() {
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Information(String address, String name, String phone_No, String suburb, String state, String postcode, String doctor, int total_score) {
        Address = address;
        Name = name;
        Phone_No = phone_No;
        Suburb = suburb;
        State = state;
        Postcode = postcode;
        Doctor = doctor;
        Total_Score = total_score;

    }

    public int getTotal_Score() {
        return Total_Score;
    }

    public void setTotal_Score(int total_Score) {
        Total_Score = total_Score;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone_No() {
        return Phone_No;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setPhone_No(String phone_No) {
        Phone_No = phone_No;
    }

    public String getSuburb() {
        return Suburb;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setSuburb(String suburb) {
        Suburb = suburb;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return Postcode;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        Postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return Doctor;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")

    public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
        Doctor = doctor;
    }
}
```

In my other class, I have used:

```
Information info = snapshot.getValue(Information.class);
assert info != null;
String txt = "Medical Clinic: " + info.getName() + "Total Score: " + info.getTotal_Score();
list.add(txt);
```

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean "doesn't work"?  An "int" (Java [primitive type](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Type)) cannot be "null".  Q: I assume "snapshop.child()" is a typo - it should be "snapshot".  Correct?  Q: Can you update your post, and show us an example of "txt"?

Comment: I think mine is called snapshot but it just returns null everytime.... I guess is because of me putting an id behind each user to store the value...